# change the text of a div during clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am appending `div`'s with ajax call, for this I made a dummy `div`, I am `cloning` the `div` and putting the data according to the data present `JSON`. I made a [dummy](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/q9cxh/) too([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/q9cxh/)). in this fiddle every time I am putting "a" as text in `div`. I want if `JSON` has particular value then the text should be changed(according to fiddle if value of i is 4 then text should be 'b' instead of 'a').. so how to do it.
following is my code(my code is too big so I'm putting dummy form)..
HTML:

```
<div class="wrp"></div>
<div class="childd"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrp{
  background-color:#aaf;
  border:1px solid orange;
  float:left;width:100%
}
.wrp .child{
  float:left;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background-color:#77c;
  border:1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
.childd{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background-color:#cdcdcd;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.childd').on('click',function(){
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
        $('.childd')
            .clone()
            .removeClass('childd')
            .addClass('child')
            .html('a')
            .appendTo('.wrp');
    }    
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/q9cxh/)

Comment: So different content only if `i` is 4? [`.html(i==4 ? 'b' : 'a')`](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/q9cxh/1/)?

Comment: @oGeez yeah some thing like that, is there any way if I could run a function at this condition. if we talk about real scenario, if array has a particular element then put particular data..for more details please visit www.findyogi.com/mobiles... there is a particualr div for a product in this div there is a div for features, so if features are available in array only then I've to populate it

Comment: Just adding an if statement and checking if I == 4?

Comment: May I ask why you've revoked your acceptance?

Comment: @oGeez sir your answer is correct but I've got one more problem.. I've added a comment to it.. check that you will understand.. if you want I will accept again I just thought it will be great if you could resolve that too... it would really be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like, you can pass a function to `html()`. The return value will be what is applied, of course:

```
$('.childd').on('click',function(){
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
        $('.childd')
            .clone()
            .removeClass('childd')
            .addClass('child')
            .html(function(){
                return i==4 ? 'b' : 'a'   
            })
            .appendTo('.wrp');
    }    
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/q9cxh/2/)

---

If you wanted to return a cloned element within `.html()` that can be done in exactly the same way:

```
.html(function(){
    return i==4 ? $(elem).clone() : 'a'
})
```

Comment: I tried your way and it works fine, but there is one more issue... what if i want to add a div instead of text.. I've tried some thing like that .append(function(){if(i==4){// here I want to clone another div and append it to same box.}}) how to do that...

Comment: You can return anything in `html()`. Try `.html('<div></div>');`

Comment: it this case I've return my html code as a string .. and that I don't want.. I want if I could clone another div and append directly to this div

Comment: please use this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/q9cxh/3/ for reference I want to add yellow one if i is 4

Comment: it would be just great if you could help me with the fiddle that I've mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: thanks a lot @oGeez... it really was very helpful.. +5 for this :)